# Disable a div and the form tag's action inside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="homeDiv">
<form action="one_file">
.....
</form> 
</div>
```

> **i need to disable the div and the action to take place**
>
> tried

```
 $("#homeDiv").off();  
 $("#homeDiv").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

but the action part is working..
Any help

Comment: Can you Show `<form></form>` full code if possible?

Comment: why dont you hide/show the div..?

Comment: i cant hide the form content . it should be shown but further actions should be blocked .

Comment: Check my edit in the answer for preventing form submit

Comment: try overlay with position absolute .. use jQuery to fit with size of div

Comment: @DKM its a paypal form button inside the div

Comment: is it `<input type="submit">`?

Comment: i got a way added on div on top of homeDiv and madeit as a cover over homediv . and made it semitransparent. and when i need i made it show and hide . thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#homeDiv").attr('disabled', true);
```

or

```
$("#homeDiv").attr("disabled","disable");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `show/hide` property to the div.since your form is inside the div you dont need to do anything with the form.

```
$("#homeDiv").hide();
```

Or

```
$("#homeDiv").attr('disabled', true);
```

Prevent form submitting by

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: i cant hide the div . and if i hide the div the form vill not be any more visible right?  anf form event preventing is not working. any other way to disable the div

Answer (score 0):

// use the following to disable div

$("#homeDiv").prop("disabled",true);

// Use the following to disable for ever tag within div

$("#homeDiv").children().prop("disabled",true);